# User props or put the props into state?

Tags: reactjs

Im following a react tutorial. There, the instructor didn't use the errors which are returning props redux directly using `this.props.errors`.

Instead, in componentWillRecieveProps, he set the props.errors to state.

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.errors) {
    this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors})
  }
}
```

what is the point of doing this? why not use this.props.errors directly?

Answer (score 2):

In general that is a bad idea and you may want to use the `props` directly.

As described in the official documentation: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-erasing-state-when-props-change

This what you want to achieve:

> The key to both is that for any piece of data, you need to pick a
>   single component that owns it as the source of truth, and avoid
>   duplicating it in other components.

And if you copy the props to the state, you would be storing the values in two different places.

Please read the entire documentation page to check out solutions

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use props directly in child or store it in state depends on how you are gonna use them

1. If the state is going to be directly derivable from props then more often than not, you should use the props directly instead of maintaining it in state
2. Store the props in state only when you are faced with a situation that you want to update the value in local and only update the provider of the props on say a confirm action. An example of this scenario is when you have an input component whose value is being provided by parent as props, but any change you would want to keep track locally and then onSubmit action you can pass back the value to the parent. This is an example of an uncontrolled implementation of an Input.